Should MediaWiki's LocalSettings.php be owned by www-data or root?
I help maintain an internal server (Ubuntu 20.04.6) for my research group and am still teaching myself the ins and outs of server administration. The server hosts a variety of services, including MongoDB, an annotation web app, and a MediaWiki app. Last year I worked on upgrading MongoDB from v3.4 to v6, which required some non-trivial steps like changing ownership of some /var/run, /var/log, /data, and /usr files (nothing under /var/www, though); I'd tried to be careful not to mess up anything catastrophically and practiced on virtual machines prior to the actual upgrade.
After all was said and done with the upgrade (which overall seemed to go well), I noticed some issues with our other services hosted on our server. Most of these involved updating relevant python packages within Flask apps, which did not take too much work. Now, most things are fixed, but a big issue is we cannot access our MediaWiki app:

Typing https://server.xxx.xxx/wiki into the browser, we get a 404 error
Typing https://server.xxx.xxx/wiki/index.php immediately redirects to another service of ours (a Solr search engine) that looks like https://server.xxx.xxx/solr/xxx/browse.

I have been looking through the files in our MediaWiki app and noticed that /var/www/server_root/wiki/LocalSettings.php is owned by root, while everything else in the directory is owned by www-data.
Before I start changing ownership, should something like LocalSettings.php be owned by root or by www-data in order for our MediaWiki app to be served correctly?

Generally it is better for the .php files to be owned by www-data, but this is not a hard rule as Apache can read files owned by other users so long as it has read permissions. If Apache is presenting a 404 or redirecting, it may be worth looking first at the .htaccess file in the wiki directory to see if there is a redirect. Checking the logs in /var/log/apache could also shed some light into why a redirect took place.

that is easy: it is NEVER root.

In general it's best if your PHP files are not owned by www-data since that would allow the application to change its own source code, which can increase the impact of security vulnerabilities.
But for diagnosing errors, ownership is not very relevant. All that matters is that www-data should be able to read all PHP files (and if you use cronjobs and use a different user for those, that user should too). Ownership is neither necessary nor sufficient for that.

In MediaWiki, LocalSettings.php is the configuration file that contains site-specific settings and customizations for your installation. This file is generated during the initial setup process and is essential for defining how your wiki operates.
Quote from Security section in LocalSettings.php manual:

The webserver user must have access to this file.

In your case, the problem may be that the web server cannot read the file. In Ubuntu, the web server uses the www-data user by default. You can change the owner of the file like this:
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/server_root/wiki/LocalSettings.php

